# Appending characters to RichTextBox from a handheld barcode scanner without it creating a new line for each character in the serial number

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm building an app that for a coworker that allows the user to scan a barcode using a handheld scanner. The app will automatically append that barcode to a RichTextBox. I have it fully working except for one problem:

**When a user scans a barcode, it scans each character in a new line**. Example:

```
A 1:20 PM
R 1:20 PM
C 1:20 PM
0 1:20 PM
1 1:20 PM
```

instead of

```
ARC01 1:20 PM
```

Can someone tell me what am I missing in my code below?

```
   Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged

    Dim currentTime As String = Format(TimeOfDay, "HH:mm:ss")

    RichTextBox1.AppendText(" " + currentTime + vbLf)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably whatever driver is feeding the input is doing it one char at a time. If you don't have control over that code, and you have a static number of chars in your bar code, you could wait for the line to contain that many chars and *then* add the space, time stamp and linefeed.
Something like

```
Dim lastLine As String
lastLine = RichTextBox1.Lines.Last

If lastLine.Length = 5 Then
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(" " + currentTime + vbLf)
End If
```

Comment: This resolves the issue. Thank you. But What if the barcodes weren't a static number? Let's say I find out they'll be scanning barcodes that contain either 5, 9, or 11 characters? I'll see if I can write something to accommodate that.

Comment: You could wait a few hundred milliseconds to see if there are more characters coming, but the problem with that is that they may scan two bar codes in rapid succession. You could investigate to see if the scanner somehow announces the end of the scan; perhaps it's an option for it to provide a line feed, for example, which you could then insert your date stamp in front of.

Comment: @user2300114 - many barcode readers will put a start and end character at the beginning and end of the scanned data.  You can check to see if the reader you are using allows that.